# Table or Grid plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Can someone suggest a wordpress plugin that I can use to build a simple table like the one on this page:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/blueprint/
Basically a very simple table or grid for a static page.

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of plugins out there to add simple tables to pages or posts. If you want something specific, you'll have to code it exactly, but some of these may help:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/mce-table-buttons/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/